# is there a way to specify variable number of columns for a CSV uploader in solr?

Tags: solr

i'm using the CSVupdateHandler to index CSV files into Solr. my Csv files have variable number of fields in every line ( eg 4 fields in line one 6 in line 2 and so on ... ).

```
      line1:field1,field2,field3,field4 
      line2:field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6
      line3:field1,field2,field3,field4
```

So is there a way to specify variable no of fieldnames ?? what i want it to do is to index 4 colums if there are four fields and index 6 if there are six. any other alternative way to achieve this is appreciated too :) thanks !

UPDATE :

```
let me describe the situation ....
```

i have a file with CSV data like show above. i use the fieldnames parameter to specify the field names that Solr has to use. since every LINE in my file does not have a Set number of CSValues i cannot have a standard header set for this file without me having to pad some lines with null values. Eg. when i upload the above file with 6 header fields defined lines 1 and 3 will throw an error and if i use 4 header fields line 2 throws an error.. iwant to know if there is a way to specify the header fields such that the above condition works ...or do i have to transform my file into eqal length fields with padded dummy values ??

Comment: Yes, you just pad your CSV to ensure every line has the equal size of column will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this : specify custom fields with default values in schema.xml. to account for the extra two fields in some of the lines ! the schema.xml provided  has plenty of examples !!

ALTERNATE :  u can also define a custom updateRequestProcessor and add fields based on conditions using java . and specify this processor as a part of the update processor chain in your request handler.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want column 5 and 6 map to? One way or another you need to let Solr know? In which case, you just do empty comas for missing items.

On the other hand, if you are trying to provide multi-values into a single field, than maybe you should have your field separators set to something else, and have comas as value separators.

Try thinking what you want Solr to see and work backwards from that.